# What is the difference between operations on Channel vs operations on ChannelHandlerContext

Tags: netty, netty4

I am just starting out with Netty and I have a question about `Channel` and `ChannelHandlerContext`

From what I have read so far, `Channel` can be seen as an abstraction over underlying socket where `IO` happens, while `ChannelHandlerContext` is an object used for passing information amongst channel handlers within a channel pipeline.

Is the above accurate?

Because now I am looking at a some code base that uses Netty and examples online, I find same operations that seems to be both on `Channel` and also on `ChannelHandlerContext`. For example:

```
ctx.channel().write();
vs
ctx.write();
```

or

```
ctx.channel().alloc()
vs
ctx.alloc()
```

Question is, why are these similar operations defined both on Channel`and also on`ChannelHandlerContext`? Are they different in any ways? Under which conditions should one be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Channel`.* starts at the tail of the pipeline while `Channel`.* starts from the handler that the context belongs too. Usually in a `ChannelHandler` you always want to use `ChannelHandlerContext` while outside you mostly want to use `Channel`.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the first sentence